# DropDownList in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Category)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Category)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Category)
</div>
```

This gives me a label and a text box. How can I get a drop down list with static select items in place of the text box. Please help. I am new to ASP.NET MVC. I need solution / advice in Razor syntax.

Comment: @marc_s : I agree. It took me a while to register. It wont let me vote or accept answer until I registered and then there was a site error with OpenId. Didnt let me vote until now.

Answer (score 10):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor( model => model.Category, new SelectList(new [] {"cat1", "cat2", "cat3"}) );
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you would populate a DropDownList using Model, View and Controller.

First the view

```
@using Website.Models
@model PageWithSelectList
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@Html.DropDownList("DayOfWeek", Model.DaysOfWeek)
```

Then the Controller and Action method

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Website.Models;

namespace Website.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = new PageWithSelectList();
            model.DayOfWeek = 3;
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

and the HTML output

```
<select id="DayOfWeek" name="DayOfWeek">
<option value="1">Sunday</option>
<option value="2">Monday</option>
<option selected="selected" value="3">Tuesday</option>
<option value="4">Wednesday</option>
<option value="5">Thursday</option>
<option value="6">Friday</option>
<option value="7">Saturday</option>
</select>
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to fill your dropdownlist is by using the viewbag.

Controller:

```
public Action Create()
{
   FillViewBag();
   Return View();
}

private void FillViewBag()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> selectOptions = new List<SelectListItem>();            
        for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            SelectListItem sli = new SelectListItem();
            sli.Text = "Option " + i.ToString();
            sli.Value = i.ToString();
            selectOptions.Add(sli)
        }
        ViewBag.SelectOptions = selectOptions;
     }
```

In your View:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.yourProp, ViewBag.SelectOptions as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the foolowing code

**Controler**

```
var list = new SelectList(new[]
                                          {
                                              new {ID="1",Name="Employee"},
                                              new{ID="2",Name="Debtor"},
                                              new{ID="3",Name="Supplier"},
                                               new{ID="4",Name="Patient"},
                                          },
                           "ID", "Name", 1);
                ViewData["list"] = list;

                return View();
```

**View**

```
<div class="editor-field">

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.type,ViewData["list"] as SelectList,
 new { style = "width: 100px;"})

</div>
```